# Objective-C set variable to what is returned from method

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, nsurl

I have this code:

```
-(NSURL *)urlOfCurrentlyPlayingInPlayer:(AVPlayer *)player{
// get current asset
AVAsset *currentPlayerAsset = player.currentItem.asset;

// make sure the current asset is an AVURLAsset
if (![currentPlayerAsset isKindOfClass:AVURLAsset.class]) return nil;

// return the NSURL
return [(AVURLAsset *)currentPlayerAsset URL];

}
```

why can't i just do this?

```
NSURL *currentSong=[urlOfCurrentlyPlayingInPlayer:_audioPlayer1];
```

the error message is "Expected expression" with the N of NSURL underlined in red

sorry for the noob question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `urlOfCurrentlyPlayingInPlayer` is declared in the same class:

```
NSURL *currentSong = [self urlOfCurrentlyPlayingInPlayer:_audioPlayer1];
```

If it's an instance method of some other class it would be

```
NSURL *currentSong = [myInstanceOfSomeOtherClass urlOfCurrentlyPlayingInPlayer:_audioPlayer1];
```